# How to change polarity at 120V DC using DPDT?

Tags: led, dpdt, hvdc

I have a strand of LED Christmas lights. Each "bulb" has two LEDs - one is color and the other is white - the polarity on the string determines which of the two LED lights up. Pressing the button changes modes - it flips the current direction, changing from white -> color (and back) and also has fade up/down modes.

My goal is to automate this over WiFi using something like the ESP8266. I'm an electronics newbie, but here's what I've got so far.

Mains @ 120 VAC --> Rectifier (~110 VDC) --> [ ?? PWM dimmer of some sort, controlled by ESP8266 ??] --> double DPDT relay (as H-bridge?) which can swap polarity --> LEDs.

My questions:

1. Will this work?
2. Any ideas for a PWM dimmer device?
3. As I said, I'm a total newbie; I don't know where I should be sourcing parts. Any ideas on where to find these things? Specifically I was having trouble finding the DPDTs that can handle 110V.

Is this item: DS2Y-S-DC3V likely to work as expected above?

Comment: There is a technical difficulty switching DC above ~30V because of arc generation. There won't be as many as for lower voltages.

Comment: Keep in mind that your third question about sourcing parts is still off-topic here.

Comment: Noted. If anyone answers question 3, I will ignore it.

Comment: @DaveTweed, Perhaps you could point me to a community that is more willing to help?